# Detecting double and single tap on UITableViewCell to perform two action

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitapgesturerecognizer, uitableviewautomaticdimension

I have a `PFQueryTableViewController` in which I am trying to learn some tableView interactions.

What I currently have: The tableView cell increases its height on a tap `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` or I can basically segue cell related data to next viewController using `performSegueWithIdentifier` together with `prepareForSegue` using a single tap.

In the below code, if I comment the "Tap code to increases height of tableView cell" code, I can detect double tap. Other wise the single tap increases the height as the code is inside didSelect block.

What I need:
On Single tap, cell height increases or decrease. While the cell height is increased, if I double tap, it should segue cell data to next `UIViewController`.

If not, the single tap should increase or decrease the height. And double tap should segue cell data to next `UIViewController`

Code is as below:

```
var selectedCellIndexPath: NSIndexPath?
var SelectedCellHeight = CGFloat() // currently set to 480.0 tableView height
var UnselectedCellHeight = CGFloat() // currently set to 300.0 tableView unselected hight
  ....

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    if let selectedCellIndexPath = selectedCellIndexPath {
        if selectedCellIndexPath == indexPath {
            return SelectedCellHeight
        }
    }
    return UnselectedCellHeight
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as! DataViewTableViewCell!
    if cell == nil {
        cell = DataViewTableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "cell")
    }

// Below is the double Tap gesture recognizer code in which
// The single tap is working, double tap is quite difficult to get 
// as the cell height increases on single tap of the cell

    let doubleTap = UITapGestureRecognizer()
        doubleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 2
        doubleTap.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1
        tableView.addGestureRecognizer(doubleTap)

        let singleTap = UITapGestureRecognizer()
        singleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
        singleTap.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1
        singleTap.requireGestureRecognizerToFail(doubleTap)
        tableView.addGestureRecognizer(singleTap)

// Tap code to increases height of tableView cell

    if let selectedCellIndexPath = selectedCellIndexPath {
        if selectedCellIndexPath == indexPath {
            self.selectedCellIndexPath = nil
            cell.postComment.fadeIn()
            cell.postCreatorPicture.alpha = 1
            cell.postDate.fadeIn()
          //  cell.postTime.fadeIn()
            cell.postCreator.fadeIn()
        } else {
            self.selectedCellIndexPath = indexPath
        }
    } else {
        selectedCellIndexPath = indexPath
    }
    tableView.beginUpdates()
    tableView.endUpdates()
}



func doubleTap() {
        print("Double Tap")
    }

func singleTap() {
        print("Single Tap")
    }
```

The other way I can make it work is, if I can get `NSIndexPath` of selected cell outside of `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` code, I can basically use the double tap to perform if else to get the required action. Can you get `NSIndexPath` outside the tableView default blocks?

Comment: you can pass you cell object with delegate and find the indexpath with :
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell];

Answer (score 3):

Got it working!

First: Define var customNSIndexPath = NSIndexPath() and add the below code inside the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` code block.

```
customNSIndexPath = indexPath
        print(customNSIndexPath)
```

Second: Remove "Tap code to increases height of tableView cell" code from `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` and add to the `singleTap()` function. And perform segue using the `doubleTap()`.

```
func doubleTap() {
        print("Double Tap")
        performSegueWithIdentifier("MainToPost", sender: self)
    }

    func singleTap() {
        print("Single Tap")
        var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as! DataViewTableViewCell!
        if cell == nil {
            cell = DataViewTableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "cell")
        }

        if let selectedCellIndexPath = selectedCellIndexPath {
            if selectedCellIndexPath == customNSIndexPath {
                self.selectedCellIndexPath = nil

            } else {
                self.selectedCellIndexPath = customNSIndexPath
            }
        } else {
            selectedCellIndexPath = customNSIndexPath
        }
        tableView.beginUpdates()
        tableView.endUpdates()
    }
```

This is how you screw up working late without sleeping. It was the easiest thing to do. Thanks

Note: If someone has better solution or this one is wrong in some xyz case, please do comment. If yours is better it would really help others.

Answer (score 0):

```
var lastClick: TimeInterval = 0.0
var lastIndexPath: IndexPath? = nil

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) 
{
    let now: TimeInterval = Date().timeIntervalSince1970
    if (now - lastClick < 0.3) && (lastIndexPath?.row == indexPath.row ) {
        print("Double Tap!")
    } else {
        print("Single Tap!")
    }
    lastClick = now
    lastIndexPath = indexPath
}
```