# UITableView selected row center like UIPickerView in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uipickerview, uianimation

What I want to do: Make UITableView selected row animate like a UIPickerView on selection.

I have a `UITableViewController` in which I am displaying `UIImages` in rows from Parse backend. The cell size is almost half of the users screen. I have used `tapGestureRecognizer` "Single Tap" to increase/decrease the cell height to show selected cell images and "Double Tap" to segue data to next view. If anyone is interested to know, here is the [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34702700/detecting-double-and-single-tap-on-uitableviewcell-to-perform-two-action/34702863#34702863) to it.

Now the problem is, when I tap on any specific cell image the cell increases in height as needed but if the selected cell is not centered when tapped (i.e: I have bottom half of the cell Row-1 and top half of cell Row-2 on users screen) the cell which has its height increased is partially visible.

So I was wondering if there is way with which we can have the selected cell automatically centered on tap? Similar to UIPickerView?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution. Use the didSelectRowAtIndexPath delegate method and then scroll to the provided indexpath.row of the tableview accordingly.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    yourTableView.scrollToRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, atScrollPosition: .Top , animated: true)
}
```